# Correlation Id errors for Kafka console producer and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 2 Kafkas backed by 3 ZK nodes. I want to test the Kafka nodes by running the kafka-console-producer and -consumer locally on each node.

So I SSH into one of my Kafka brokers using 2 different terminals. In terminal #1 I run the consumer like so:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper a.b.c.d:2181 --topic test1
```

Where a.b.c.d is the private IP of one of my 3 ZK nodes.

Then in terminal #2 I run the producer like so:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test1
```

I am able to start both the consumer and producer just fine without any issues.

However, in the producer terminal, if I "fire" a message at the test1 topic by entering some text (such as "hello") and hitting the ENTER key, I immediately begin seeing this:

```
[2017-01-17 19:45:57,353] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {test1=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-17 19:45:57,372] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {test1=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-17 19:45:57,477] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {test1=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-17 19:45:57,582] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3 : {test1=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
...and it keeps going!
```

And, in the consumer terminal, even though I don't get any errors when I start the consumer, after about 30 seconds I get the following warning message:

```
[2017-01-17 19:46:07,292] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 1 for topics [Set(test1)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(1,ip-x-y-z-w.ec2.internal,9092)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:80)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:79)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:124)
at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59)
at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:94)
at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
```

Interestingly, ip-x-y-z-w.ec2.internal is the private DNS for the other Kafka broker, so perhaps this is some kind of failure during interbroker communication?

Any ideas as to what is going on here and what I can do to troubleshoot?

---

#### Update

Here's my entire `server.properties` file for both Kafkas nodes:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.host.name=<private-aws-ec2-ip-addr>.ec2.internal
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
broker.id=1
port=9092
num.partitions=4
zookeeper.connect=zkA:2181,zkB:2181,zkC:2181
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
offset.metadata.max.bytes=4096
```

Please let me know if anything looks like config smell.

Comment: Try to set 'advertised.listeners' for all brokers.

Comment: Thanks @amethystic (+1) - please see my update which includes my `server.properties` file. Same exact problem even after full restart of Kafka + ZK nodes.

Comment: Do you have zkA,zkB,zkC names entry in host file with corresponding ip addresses?

Comment: Thanks @Paresh (+1) - **yes** they are in `/etc/hosts` with their correct (respective) IPs

Comment: With recalling your question for a while,  I started to be confused a little bit. What's your exact problem? Producer cannot be working? Or consumer? Or both?  Are the warnings in the producer transient? For the consumer side, could you try 'telnet ip-x-y-z-w.ec2.internal 9092' to see if the socket is created successfully.